# How to properly remove the jagged edges of adjacent shapes

Tags: c++, geometry, polygons

So I have this map which is divided in provinces, each province (obviously) adjacent to a couple others, each one having a different shape. The source image for these shapes is low resolution, so I wrote some code to trace each shape and store it. Now, that's all nice and well, but the whole reason for me wanting to trace it was so I can vectorize it, so that said shapes don't look jagged when you zoom in. Here's what some of them look like when the edges are left as they are (I've highlighted one of the shapes):
[image: no edge removal]

To remove the above seen jagged edges, I first tried this:

```
std::vector<sf::Vector2f> removeRightAngles(const std::vector<sf::Vector2f>& points)
{
    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> returnValue;
    for (std::vector<sf::Vector2f>::const_iterator it = points.begin(), end = points.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        const sf::Vector2f A = it != points.begin() ? *(it - 1) : points.at(points.size() - 1), B = *it, C = it + 1 != end ? *(it + 1) : *points.begin());
        if (threePointsMakeALine(A, B, C)))
        {
            returnValue.push_back(B);
        }
        else
        {
            const sf::Vector2f candidateA((A.x + B.x) / 2.0f, (A.y + B.y) / 2.0f),
                candidateB((B.x + C.x) / 2.0f, (B.y + C.y) / 2.0f);
            if (!elementIncludedInVector(candidateA, returnValue)) returnValue.push_back(candidateA);
            if (!elementIncludedInVector(candidateB, returnValue)) returnValue.push_back(candidateB);
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I take the average between the current point and the next and previous ones respectively so that shapes don't overlap or have space between them afterwards. The problem is that this code produces the following results:
[image: edge removal]
Notice the holes where different shapes meet.
I tried avoiding them by modifying first two lines of the for statement to this:

```
const sf::Vector2f A = it != points.begin() ? *(it - 1) : points.at(points.size() - 1), B = *it, C = it + 1 != end ? *(it + 1) : *points.begin(),
    D = it + 3 >= points.end() ? *(it + 3 - points.size()) : *(it + 3), E = it - 3 < points.begin() ? *(it - 3 + points.size()) : *(it - 3);
if (threePointsMakeALine(A, B, C) || threePointsMakeALine(B, C, D) || threePointsMakeALine(E, A, B))
```

Which produced the following results:

[image: improved edge removal]

[image: improved edge removal]

[image: improved edge removal]

An improvement, but still not the desired effect.
So, finally, my question is, how can I go about removing the jagged edges of such shapes so that they continue to have no holes between them?

Here's what the point coordinates look like without changing them, using the first method and then the second: http://pastebin.com/AaNsw7F3

Comment: Would you mind dumping some test data on http://pastebin.com/ (or something similar).

Comment: Hopefully, this is what you meant by test data: http://pastebin.com/AaNsw7F3